# GPIO set mode statement error

Tags: gpio

I am a Python newbie.  I am following a tutorial to run an SPI 1.8" TFT display. A term (or is it a module?) `InitIO()` is defined as follows:

```
def InitIO():  
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO,BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(false)
    for pin in pins:
        GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(SCLK,0)           #start with clock low
```

I understand the purpose of the module as follows:  It sets up three GPIO pins as SPI clock, data and data command. However, when `InitIO()` is called it produces an error:

```
NameError: name 'BOARD' is not defined
```

There is no mention in the tutorial about identifying BOARD.  I have also tried substituting BCM instead of BOARD and I get the same error, with BCM substituted for BOARD in the error.

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: It's GPIO.BOARD (dot instead of comma)

Comment: Avoid answering in comments, @Dirk, care to post an answer instead?

Comment: @Ghanima In these cases, I find it almost embarrassing to make it a proper answer. Done it anyway.

Comment: Well, there certainly is an amount of discussion about the topic, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320364/3984613) but as of now it is standing policy of StackExchange to *avoid* answering questions in comments as it circumvents the mechanisms that are supposed to ensure quality of the Q&A, i.e. voting. Short answers, btw, are not necessarily embarrassing.

Answer (score 4):

It's a constant defined in the RPi.GPIO module, so it has the same prefix as the RPi.GPIO functions.

In your case that's GPIO, so the correct value is `GPIO.BOARD` (using a dot instead of comma). The full function call is

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```